# Obtaining real and positive solution of a polynomial equation in wxMaxima

Tags: maxima, wxmaxima

I'd like to solve the following equation in wxMaxima:

```
k*A*((T_2-T_1)/L)=ε*σ*A*(T_1^4-T_a^4)
```

for `T_1`. The problem is that with regular `Solve` and `Solve_to_poly` I get extremely long outputs but not what I would expect. I need a real and positive solution since `T_1` is a temperature in Kelvins. I can substitute the values but I'd prefer to get a symbolic formula as output. Is there a way to get such a solution in wxMaxima?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, it's not possible to solve this equation in such a way that a symbolic solution in form of a formula for `T1` is obtained. Thus, I had to substitute the values and then solve for unknown `T1`. Either using `float(solve([...],[T1]))` which gives 4 solutions (with only one being real and positive - the one of interest) or using `find_root(...,T1,0,1000)`. Lower and upper bounds for `T1` (0 K - 1000 K) can be selected based on the physics of the problem.